# Java API for Rational Synergy/CM?

Tags: java, cm-synergy

Does anyone know if there exists a java API for Rational Synergy/CM?
I need to perform queries from inside a small java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen source code of Telelogic Synergy plugin for CruiseControl.NET continuous integration server and connectivity with Synergy was done by executing its command line tool and parsing output.

Comment: Yes, I created my own Java class that called the ccm executable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a Eclipse plugin for CM Synergy ( old name Continuus), 
you can download it from IBM spport site, 
The company Telelogic was bought by IBM.